# How to download a file using URLDownloadToFile?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I use the code below to download a file from received Outlook mail.

The received mail has several links. One hyperlink contains the word "download" and contains the file to download.

The size of the downloaded file is always 9KB or 10KB. The actual file size is 10 or 12 MB.  I can't open the file due to the file not being properly downloaded.

```
Option Explicit

#If VBA7 Then
 Private Declare PtrSafe Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" Alias 
  "URLDownloadToFileA" _
                        (ByVal pCaller As LongPtr, _
                        ByVal szURL As String, _
                        ByVal szFileName As String, _
                        ByVal dwReserved As LongPtr, _
                        ByVal lpfnCB As LongPtr) As LongPtr



#Else
Private Declare Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" Alias 
"URLDownloadToFileA" _
                        (ByVal pCaller As Long, _
                        ByVal szURL As String, _
                        ByVal szFileName As String, _
                        ByVal dwReserved As Long, _
                        ByVal lpfnCB As Long) As Long
#End If


Sub ExportAllHyperlinksandDownload()
Dim objSelection As Selection
Dim objMail As MailItem
Dim objMailDocument As Document
Dim objHyperlink As Hyperlink
Dim url As String
Dim HttpReq As Object
Dim Ret As Long

Set objSelection = Outlook.Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection

If Not (objSelection Is Nothing) Then
    For Each objMail In objSelection
        Set objMailDocument = objMail.GetInspector.WordEditor
        If objMailDocument.Hyperlinks.Count > 0 Then
            url = objMailDocument.Hyperlinks(5).Address
            Ret = URLDownloadToFile(0, url, "C:\Temp\" & objMailDocument.Hyperlinks(5).TextToDisplay, 0, 0)
            If Ret = 0 Then
                MsgBox ("Files Downloaded !")
            Else
                MsgBox ("Error in Download! Please try again later !")
            End If
        End If
    Next
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I took your code and upgraded just a little bit to download every link from selected email, not only 5th and giving proper name of the file (name of the file just like it is named in download source) - and it is working for me.

```
Sub ExportAllHyperlinksandDownload()
Dim objSelection As Selection
Dim objMail As MailItem
Dim objMailDocument As Object
Dim objHyperlink As Hyperlink
Dim hlink As Hyperlink
Dim url As String
Dim HttpReq As Object
Dim ret As LongPtr
Dim xmlhttp As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
Dim i As Long
Dim nejm As String
Dim pos As String
Dim nejm2 As String

Set objSelection = Outlook.Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection

If Not (objSelection Is Nothing) Then

    For Each objMail In objSelection

        Set objMailDocument = objMail.GetInspector.WordEditor

        For i = 1 To objMailDocument.Hyperlinks.Count
            url = objMailDocument.Hyperlinks(i).Address

            xmlhttp.Open "GET", url, False
            xmlhttp.send

            nejm = xmlhttp.getResponseHeader("Content-Disposition")
            If nejm <> "" Then
                nejm = Replace(nejm, """", "")
                pos = InStr(1, nejm, "=")
                nejm2 = Mid(nejm, pos + 1, (Len(nejm) - (pos)))
            Else
                nejm2 = FileNameFromPath(url) '"File.jpg" 'GetFilenameFromPath(myURL)
            End If

            ret = URLDownloadToFile(0, url, "C:\Temp\" & nejm2, 0, 0)
            If ret = 0 Then
                MsgBox ("Files Downloaded !")
            Else
                MsgBox ("Error in Download! Please try again later !")
            End If
        Next

    Next

End If

End Sub
```